# cannot delete elements that are in xml

Tags: php, xml, laravel

I want to delete one of the tags in xml like `<tpk>` or `<img>` by calling the variable that stores the name of the tag to be deleted
, I tried with the following code, but nothing happened in xml...

This is the xml code that I want to delete:

```
<main_asset>
 <tpk name="tpk_game_img">
    <type>Image</type>
    <link>https://aws-asta-s3-01.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/unity-asset/TPK/Android/</link>
    <ver>0.0.1</ver>
 </tpk>
 <tpk name="tpk_game_audio">
    <type>Audio</type>
    <link>https://aws-asta-s3-01.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/unity-asset/TPK/Android/</link>
    <ver>0.0.1</ver>
 </tpk>
 <img name="main_java_img">
    <type>2</type>
    <link>linkwoi</link>
    <ver>0.0.4</ver>
 </img>
</main_asset>
```

this is the function:

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        $pk     =   $request->id;
        $tag    =   $request->name;
        $xml    =   new \DomDocument();
        $xml->load('../public/assets/xml/Android/asset_game2.xml');
        $xpath  =   new \DOMXPATH($xml);

        foreach($xpath->query("/main_asset/".$tag."[name = '$pk']") as $node )
        {
            $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
        }

        $xml->formatoutput = true;

        //save xml local
        $xml->save('../public/assets/xml/Android/asset_game2.xml');
        $xmllocal = "../public/assets/xml/Android/asset_game2.xml";

        //save xml into aws s3
        $PathS3   = 'unity-asset/XML/Android/asset_game2.xml';
        Storage::disk('s3')->put($PathS3, file_get_contents($xmllocal));

        return back()->with('success', 'Data berhasil di hapus');




    }
```

Comment: you need a regressive loop to remove elements from DOMNodelist, so do it in reverse  using a for loop

Comment: @Kevin Actually, not in this case. Only with live results from methods like `DOMElement::getElementsByTagName()`. `name` is an attribute so the expressions is missing the `@`: `"/main_asset/tpk[@name = 'tpk_game_audio']"`